# std::ranges implementation for keeping the longest sequences of repeating values in a sorted array

Tags: c++, std-ranges

If I have a sorted array and want to keep only the longest sequences of repeating values, is there a straightforward solution with `std::ranges/views/projections` to avoid writing long code like in my [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/scvv3rEff)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

auto keep_longest_sequences(auto first, auto last)
{
    auto dest_init = first;
    auto dest = first;

    decltype(std::distance(first, last)) max_range_size = 0;

    while (first != last) {
        auto it_next_val = std::upper_bound(first, last, *first);
        auto size = std::distance(first, it_next_val);

        if (size > max_range_size) {
            max_range_size = size;
            dest = dest_init;
            std::copy(first, it_next_val, dest);
            dest += size;
        }
        else if (size == max_range_size) {
            std::copy(first, it_next_val, dest);
            dest += size;
        }
        first = it_next_val;
    }

    return dest;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
    
    v.erase(keep_longest_sequences(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());

    for (auto vi : v) {
            std::cout << vi << " ";
    }
}
```

The expected result is:

> 2 2 2 2 7 7 7 7

If this could be parameterized with N longest (not 2 like here, but with N longest length), it would be even better.

The expected result with N = 2 would be:

> 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 6 6 6 7 7 7 7

Answer (score 2):

You can group repeated elements into subranges and filter based on their size, something like:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
auto repeat_size = 4;
auto r = v | std::views::chunk_by(std::ranges::equal_to{})
           | std::views::filter([repeat_size](auto r) { return r.size() >= repeat_size; })
           | std::views::join;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YbeE1xe4z)

If you want to find the max repeat size, you can use `ranges::max` to find the largest subranges:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
const auto max_repeat_size = std::ranges::max(
  v | std::views::chunk_by(std::ranges::equal_to{})
    | std::views::transform(std::ranges::size)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps. The only issue that now we need to calculate this `repeat_size`. Can this be done in one pass with ranges? If not, is there a way to calculate this `repeat_size` in a separate path with ranges, natively?

Comment: Another question, is there a way to do this in the same container inplace, without creating a new range? If I write `v.erase(std::ranges::copy(r, v.begin()).out, v.end());` would it still keep the lazy evaluation and lead to inplace operation without creating actual array for `r` in memory? If not, would it help if I write `v.erase(std::ranges::copy(v|<all-these-ops>, v.begin()).out, v.end());` and would it be safe? (Posted as a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77962688/stdranges-inplace-lazy-evaluation)).

Comment: So, just to make sure you saw my previous comment, is there a way to calculate `repeat_size` natively with ranges, preferably in one pass with the main algorithm like it is done in the code example in the question above?