# std::ranges inplace lazy evaluation

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

In case I have some `std::ranges` pipe which reduces the original data in the following way:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
auto repeat_size = 4;
auto r = v | std::views::chunk_by(std::ranges::equal_to{})
           | std::views::filter([repeat_size](auto r) { return r.size() >= repeat_size; })
           | std::views::join;
```

and I want to make this inplace in the vector `v` without creating a new intermediate array in memory (which could be quite large), keep it lazy evaluation, would this solve my task:

```
v.erase(std::ranges::copy(r, v.begin()).out, v.end());
```

If not, would this help:

```
v.erase(std::ranges::copy(v 
           | std::views::chunk_by(std::ranges::equal_to{})
           | std::views::filter([repeat_size](auto r) { return r.size() >= repeat_size; })
           | std::views::join),
           v.begin()).out, v.end());
```

I tested with the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s3Mo8e8K3) and see that the code itself works, getting the result inplace, but I am not sure about the internal implementation. Would it create temporary array in memory or not? Would it be as efficient as a straightforward implementation with for-loop?

If neither of these work, could you please explain what is the reason and how this could be achieved?

*In case somebody could give me a clue how to check how this work internally with ranges (does it allocate memory or not, if lazy evaluation still works, etc.) except debugging the source code (maybe just some handy tools, wrappers, etc.), please share.*

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/copy): "*The behavior is undefined if the source and the destination ranges overlap.*"

Comment: I believe `auto r = v ` does not copy. If you print addresses of elements `v` and `r` you can see that they are the same. Internally simple range should be a view (begin, end, that is no copy here). But I have no idea how filters work.

Comment: @康桓瑋, thank you for catching this. Am I correct in thinking that in this case even `std::ranges::copy_result`(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/copy) won't help, since the result is anyway in the range of the source? If so, is there any way for inplace processing here? I don't want to create another container for the results.