# Could views::move help in implementing inplace algorithms?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

Could [`views::move`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2446r0.html) help in making algorithms like this one inplace (putting the resulting data in the source container)?

The fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s3Mo8e8K3) shows the code that works, but has undefined behaviour.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 };

    auto repeat_size = 4;
    auto r = v | std::views::chunk_by(std::ranges::equal_to{})
        | std::views::filter([repeat_size](auto r) { return r.size() >= repeat_size; })
        | std::views::join;

    v.erase(std::ranges::copy(r, v.begin()).out, v.end());

    for (auto vi : v) {
        std::cout << vi << " ";
    }
}
```

**What code does**

I have a sorted array and want to keep only the longest sequences of repeating values in the **same** array (vector).

The expected result is:

> 2 2 2 2 7 7 7 7

Is there a way to use [`views::move`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2446r0.html) to rework it somehow in such a way:

```
auto repeat_size = 4;
v | std::views::chunk_by(std::ranges::equal_to{})
  | std::views::filter([repeat_size](auto r) { return r.size() >= repeat_size; })
  | std::views::join
  | std::views::move;
```

If so, some questions:

1. How to know the end of the resulting sequence to erase the leftovers?
2. Will this code be effective in terms of extra temporary memory allocations any copying?
3. What is known about the `views::move` implementations for compilers (for example, I can't see in the recent version of VS 2002).

If not, the only question is how std::ranges algorithms with pipes supposed to generate inplace results? I believe, this is a very common task.

Comment: @PaulSanders, it comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958262/stdranges-implementation-for-keeping-the-longest-sequences-of-repeating-values) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77962688/stdranges-inplace-lazy-evaluation) questions which cover all the details. I need to keep the longest (still not finally solved there) sequences of repeating elements of the sorted array inplace. See those questions and let me know if some gaps.

Comment: @PaulSanders, my question here is not about specifics the code does, although this is easily readable from it). My question is very straightforward, how to put the results in the same array. How would you suggest reworking the question to make it the point?

Comment: @PaulSanders, are the changes above is what you meant to see?

Comment: Yes, much better, thank you, reversed my downvote

Comment: @PaulSanders, any thoughts on the topic?

Comment: Been adequately answered, I thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet won't compile. Even if somehow it compiled, it wouldn't do anything; because you didn't store the result of all those range adapters anywhere; nor did you call any algorithms on the resultant range to perform anything. The document referred in OP dates back to 2021. There are 2 std ways to achieve the required functionality:

1. C++20 `ranges::move` algorithm:

```
std::vector<int> src = {/*...*/};
std::vector<int> dst;

dst.clear();
std::ranges::move(src, back_inserter(dst));
```

2. C++23 `views::as_rvalue`:

```
std::vector<int> src = {/*...*/};
auto dst = src 
         | std::views::as_rvalue
         | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

Note that `ranges::move` has a C++11 iterator-based counterpart that lives overshadowed by its well-known parameter-passing overload:

```
std::ranges::move(begin(src), end(src), back_inserter(dst));
```

Bottom line is that the functionality has been present since C++11. But also note that `views::as_rvalue` is shipped with C++23, which means a follow-up revision of the referenced proposal has been finalized.
In either case you are responsible to guarantee that moving from source range is safe(i.e it is the result of a `views::transform` or a prvalue or cleared/reassigned after the move...).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the misprint, in my source code I meant `std::views::move`, not `std::move` and code doesn't compile since all known libraries are missing `std::views::move` which is in my understanding responsible for moving the resulting values to `v', but it seems that I am wrong in my assumption here. To be sure that we are on the same page here, I don't need a new array, I want to work in the same array(inplace). I see that [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6Y3KP6n54) works, but not sure in terms of efficiency (not allocating temp arrays, not making extra copy). Could you, please, review?

Comment: In case my data in the vector is POD, what exactly `std::views::as_rvalue` supposed to do? I see that in my particular case, your code works even without `std::views::as_rvalue`.

Comment: For POD types, move and copy make no difference. Buf if you have some resource managing object type(string, smart pointer, image abstractions...), then copy will be expensive; in such cases if the data type has already optimized its relocation functions(move ctor & move assignment), invoking a move requesting function calls the relocation functions instead of copy.

Comment: I saw the new snippet. If it has the intended result, I see nothing wrong. Because `v` is reassigned after move. But if vector elements are of `int` - which is a trivial type(`static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<int>);`), then `as_rvalue` doesn't make any difference. `to<vector>` eventually triggers a dynamic allocation, which could be avoided, if you could remove unwanted elements in place; But the code is readable, and looks less error-prone in current state. On the plus side, the relocation of elements happens only once - which might affect  performance if elements are of complex types.

Comment: Thank you again. Not sure what you mean with the "if you could remove unwanted elements in place"; the algorithms "squeezes" the data is array, with which I mean that reading iterator always will be ahead of writing operator, so I just want to have the data written in the source array without intermediate allocation, since the array in my case could be quite big. Is this doable? Is it better to raise a new question for this or you could suggest a way to implement this in the current one?

Comment: The memory efficient way would be to identify unwanted subranges and discard them using `erase` family of member functions. to minimize data relocations you must implement a proper algorithm. The godbolt algorithm is readable and error-free( `as_rvalue` is redundant) but allocates memory.

Comment: I am easy either way. But read community guidelines before making your mind whether or not to post a new question.